# system() not executed when compiled with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++

Tags: c++, linux, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{ 
    printf("Hello\n");
    system("echo nikhil");   
    printf("Hello\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When this code is compiled with **arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++** the system call is getting skipped, all other instructions are getting executed except the **system("echo nikhil")**

Why is this happening and how to avoid the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using 
execl("/system/bin/sh","sh","test.sh")

where test.sh is my script file having echo nikhil

Answer (score 0):

> system() will not, in fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version 2, since bash 2 drops privileges on startup...
>   http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

You can try with the Exec command 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec